# X11 - Blank out the screen

Tags: c++, linux, bash, x11

I am currently using a remote software to access a computer of mine. The problem is now: I dont want anyone to see what I am doing, so I am trying to write a little tool or script that will blank out the screen.

The software is accessing the picture data using the MIT-SHM extension of X11, so I seek a possiblity to keep X11 rendering the data into the SHM, but simply not forward it to the Monitor (as if the monitor is turned off). Is there any way? As a last resort I would use XVFB, but I would rather not...

P.S.: I am seeking a programmatic attempt. Either via BASH script or C/C++.

Comment: If the people you're trying to hide from don't have physical access to the machine, you could just do `xset dpms force off` - this will turn off the monitor. It will turn on again when you wiggle the mouse, though.

Comment: Wow. that works really great. Is there a way to prevent mouse wiggling to reactivate the screen or can i somehow detect that the screen is on again?

Comment: Is that remote software `x11vnc`+`vncviewer`?

Comment: No. Its a piece of proprietary software...

Comment: `x11vnc` has a `-clientdpms` option. What it essentially does is - to call `dpms` commands to blank out display, **every time** there is a mouse/keyboard action. So, the monitor is unblanked & blanked again. This is not really visible to eyes, because of the hysteresis of the monitor. NOW, if you have access to that proprietary software's code, you can add a code to blank using dpms commands, after every kbd/mouse event. Alternately, you can use a dirty hack to keep `x11vnc -forcedpms -forever -allow 127.0.0.1 -clip 1x1+0+0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x11vnc` has options like `-clientdpms`, `-forcedpms`.

What they essentially do is - to call `dpms` commands to blank out display, **every time** there is a mouse/keyboard action. So, the monitor is unblanked & blanked again. This is not really visible to eyes, because of the hysteresis of the monitor.

NOW, if you have access to that proprietary software's code, you can add a code to blank using dpms commands, after every kbd/mouse event.

Alternately, you can use a dirty hack to keep `x11vnc -forcedpms -forever -allow 127.0.0.1 -clip 1x1+0+0` running in the background.